# Awk script to filter text output to single line

Tags: scripting, sed, awk

I have a script that is giving me an output like this:

`ruby-devel is needed by software1`
`tcl is needed by software 2`
`python3 is needed by software 3`
`ocaml is needed by software 1`

I'm new to awk but was trying to script it to get the first word, and put it in a single line (can use sed or the best way to actually do this, I couldn't do it) to be able to build an output like this:

`You need to get: ruby-devel tcl python3 ocaml`
`Run: yum install ruby-devel tcl python3 ocaml`

Any help on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using bash, something like this?

```
WORDS=$( your_script | awk '{printf("%s ",$1);}' )

printf 'You need to get: %s\n'  "${WORDS}"
printf 'Run: yum install %s'  "${WORDS}"
```

Answer (score -1):

`awk`

```sh
awk '{if ($1~/ruby|tcl|python3|ocaml/) $1="ruby-devel tcl python3 ocaml" } END { print "You need to get:", $1, "\nRun: dnf install", $1 }' $file
```